# Integral involving even order Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus, legendre-polynomials

Let $a>1$. We want to evaluate the integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_{2n}(\xi)\,d\xi}{\sqrt{a^2-\xi^2}}
\end{equation*}
Mathematica is able to evaluate special cases for various $n$, but does not give an answer for arbitrary $n$. From the special cases, we see that the integral is always of the form
\begin{equation*}
A_{1n}(a)\sqrt{a^2-1}+A_{2n}(a)\csc^{-1}(a),
\end{equation*}
where $A_{1n}(a)$ and $A_{2n}(a)$ are polynomials in $a$. So the question is:

Starting from the Rodriguez formula for $P_n(\xi)$ or using any other method, is it possible to determine the polynomials $A_{1n}(a)$ and $A_{2n}(a)$.

Incidentally, the result for this integral for $a=1$ is known, and is given by
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\pi^2}{\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)\Gamma(n+1)\right]^2}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: It seems like the mathematica package Rubi https://rulebasedintegration.org/ can calculate the integral that results from the generating function of that sequence but trying to find the series coefficients after calculating the integral seems to lead to a complicated reccurence formula. In any case, here is the generating function that I found using mathematica ($F$ is the ellipticF function)

Comment: $$\frac{2 \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{a^2}} a \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{-2 a t+t^2+1}} \left(F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{a}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)|-\frac{4 a t}{t^2-2 a t+1}\right)-F\left(\csc ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a}}}\right)|-\frac{4 a t}{t^2-2 a t+1}\right)\right)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2 a t+t^2+1}} \left(F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{a}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)|\frac{4 a t}{t^2+2 a t+1}\right)-F\left(\csc ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a}}}\right)|\frac{4 a t}{t^2+2 a t+1}\right)\right)\right)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$

Comment: @userrandrand Thanks for your answer and also introducing me to this new package `rulebasedintegration' which I was not aware of. By using the incomplete beta function, I was able to reduce the double summation in Robert's answer to a single summation. See my answer below. The motivation behind this problem is to be able to express the function as a Fourier-Legendre series.

Comment: Rubi is quite good, here is one old mathematica stack exchange answer that mentions it https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32939/86543. You can find other posts about it here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=rubi&searchOn=3

Comment: I think Rubi still has some way to go before it can catch up with Mathematica. Try the following integral from Pipes book on Applied Maths.                                                            Int[Cosh[a*x]/Cosh[Pi*x],{x,0,Infinity}]      Rubi is unable to integrate, but Mathematica can evaluate much more complicated expressions than these                                                   .

Comment: Nice example, Indeed that is a pretty simple looking integral that it failed on.  There is also the question of the time needed for the computation and the complexity of the output when both manage to find an answer. For example, If I recall correctly, I used Rubi for the integral I mentioned in my comment because mathematica was taking a long time or did not converge I do not remember.

Comment: You can find in the following link another example of where Rubi found an integral that mathematica struggled with or could not find https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182100/how-can-i-assign-first-evaluate-an-integrate-command-and-then-assign-the-integra/182104#182104

Comment: The following user also seems to mention that it often happens that Rubi can find integrals that Mathematica cannot although he did not provide examples https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181700/86543

Comment: Another advantage of  Rubi is that it can show steps although I have not really used that so I cannot say how useful it is.

Comment: Overall, It can be worth trying with Rubi if Mathematica takes a long time or maybe even if it fails (although I cannot remember if I ever used it when it failed and was not just too slow for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there's nothing very special about $P_{2n}$, it's just that $P_{2n}$ is an even polynomial.

Let's let

$$ I_k = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\xi^{2k} d\xi}{\sqrt{a^2 - \xi^2}}
= 2\int_{0}^1 \frac{\xi^{2k} d\xi}{\sqrt{a^2 - \xi^2}} $$

Further, let's take $b = 1/a$ and change variables to $t = b\xi$.  Now
we have

$$ I_k = 2 b^{-2k} \int_0^b \frac{t^{2k}\; dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} $$

where $0 \le b \le 1$. It is "well-known" that

$$ \int_0^b \frac{t^{2k}\; dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \frac{(2k-1)(2k-3) \cdots 1}{(2k)(2k-2)\cdots 2}\arcsin(b) - \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(2k-1)(2k-3)\cdots (2i+1)}{(2k)(2k-2) \cdots (2i)} b^{2i-1} \sqrt{1-b^2}   $$

and then if $P_{2m}(\xi) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} a_k \xi^{2k}$, your integral is $\sum_{k=0}^m a_k I_k$.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Robert's answer, I was able to derive the following explicit expression:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{P_{2n}(\xi)\,d\xi}{\sqrt{a^2-\xi^2}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{4^na^{2(k-1)}B_{1/a^2}\left(k-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n+k-\frac{1}{2}\right)}
{\Gamma(2k-1)\Gamma\left(k-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma(2n-2k+3)},
\end{equation*}
where $B_z(a,b)$ denotes the incomplete $\beta$ function. For $a=1$, the above expression reduces to
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{P_{2n}(\xi)\,d\xi}{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}=\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right)^2.
\end{equation*}

The above results along with the orthogonality of the Legendre polynomials allows one to express $1/\sqrt{a^2-\xi^2}$ as a Fourier-Legendre series!